# Expressions or phrasal verbs for very boring

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

In AE, how could I say something is very boring?
I know teenagers would say "it sucks" but is there anything else, phrasal verbs or expressions?

If it's something local, I would also ask you to say in what part of the country people say it.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in a thesaurus?

Comment: Ahan, but most of it is too formal and I don't know which is best and which might sound awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dragged on like a Methodist wedding" won't go down well with Methodists, but would be understandable to people who consider alcohol a vital ingredient to good wedding. (It's also not very common, but that it stuck in my mind that I heard it says something in favour of its vividness as much as it is probably best not to use it).

Less specifically, and less at the expense of any group, things "drag on" if they are both taking a long time, and boring.

"Like watching paint dry" has less risk of causing offence. (Except of course to whoever was responsible for the thing you are calling boring).

"…to tears" is often used to emphasise bordeom; "We were bored to tears", "it bored me to tears", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Be like [watching paint dry](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+watching+paint+dry): ( fromTFD)

Exciting  as  [watching paint dry](https://books.google.com/books?id=oL0IBAAAQBAJ&q=%22watching%20paint%20dry%22&dq=%22watching%20paint%20dry%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=G76vVODNF8iUNrK-g9gM&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBA)  (sarcastic) .(McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Idioms Dictionary)

> - if you say that watching an activity is like watching paint dry, you mean that it is very boring To me, watching golf on television is about as interesting as watching paint dry.